# How to fix error -bash: mean: command not found on Mac?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io

I'm trying to install mean.

First, "sudo npm install -g mean-cli". Then "mean init yourNewApp" as instructed on their website.

Result was -bash: mean: command not found. Any help? I'm thinking my $PATH is missing something but not sure what. Or maybe it's something completely else.

Comment: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and try again.

Comment: thanks. But did not help. Still get the same error message.

Comment: Strange, it works for me (also on Mac). The CLI tool is installed as `/usr/local/bin/mean`. I assume that the installation didn't yield any errors?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I don't think so. Is there way to check? Or uninstall and install again?

Comment: Try and see if this works: `/usr/local/bin/mean`. If not, you can try running `sudo npm install -g mean-cli` again to see if there are any errors popping up (warnings are not a problem).

Comment: Thanks! Installing again helped. Worked after that.